# Open Chrome trace-viewer from command line

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome includes a useful trace viewer (`chrome://tracing`). Is there a way to open a file in the trace viewer from the command line?

Comment: Have you got the method ?

Comment: No I have not..

Comment: how about now? : )

Comment: An alternative I found: `sudo apt install npm` and `sudo npm install -g speedscope` run like `speedscope <filename>`